# Setting up a parameter around a timestamp on db2

Tags: sql, timestamp, db2, dayofweek

Hello all I would like to write a query that excludes any `CHECKIN_DATE` (TIMESTAMP) between Monday 10AM to Tuesday 7AM. I found two interesting functions `DAYOFWEEK` and `HOUR`unfortunately I am not sure how to write it, this is where I am currently at with my query

```
SELECT * FROM LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT 
WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'DABL'
AND CHECKIN_DATE BETWEEN (DAYOFWEEK(CHECKIN_DATE) = '2' AND HOUR(CHECKIN_DATE) = '9') AND (DAYOFWEEK(CHECKIN_DATE = '2' AND HOUR(CHECKIN_DATE = '7')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to **exclude** any records where CHECKIN_DATE is between Monday 10AM and Tuesday 7AM, then I think the following should work for you.

```
SELECT *
  FROM LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT 
 WHERE DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'DABL'
   AND (DAYOFWEEK(CHECKIN_DATE) <= 2 AND HOUR(CHECKIN_DATE) <= '9'))
    OR (DAYOFWEEK(CHECKIN_DATE) >= 3 AND HOUR(CHECKIN_DATE) >= '7'))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, by the way would you know how I could make it appear again past 7PM on tuesday? I imagine it would be a trigger.. But I'm not sure!! Thanks Again!

Comment: Glad it helped.  Do you mean you want these records to be included i.e. appear again when you execute the query after 7PM Tuesday?

Comment: Is there a time window during which when you execute the query you do NOT want these records to show-up? If so, you could add similar conditions with the CURRENT_DATE (in DB2) to the WHERE clause

Comment: Something like this,

Comment: AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
  FROM LIST_CHECKIN_AUDIT A2
WHERE A.BILL_NUMBER = A2.BILL_NUMBER AND
A2.DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'DABL' AND
  ((DAYOFWEEK(A2.CHECKIN_DATE) = 2 AND HOUR(A2.CHECKIN_DATE) >= '10')
    OR (DAYOFWEEK(A2.CHECKIN_DATE) = 3 AND HOUR(A2.CHECKIN_DATE) <= '19')) AND 
    ((DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) = 2 AND HOUR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) >= '10')
    OR (DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) = 3 AND HOUR(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) <= '19')))